# onClick em botão dinâmico causa erro "Cannot resolve constructor Intent"

Tags: android, view, intent, button

Estou tentando criar um botão dinâmico, e no mesmo colocar a função do click.

```
Button btnJogarNovamente;
btnJogarNovamente = new Button(this);
btnJogarNovamente.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
btnJogarNovamente.setWidth(200);
btnJogarNovamente.setHeight(40);
btnJogarNovamente.setText("Jogar novamente");
btnJogarNovamente.setX(10); btnJogarNovamente.setY(40);
container.addView(btnJogarNovamente);

btnJogarNovamente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent it;
        it = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }
});
```

Porém, ocorre um erro na linha

> it = new Intent(this, Menu.class);

```
Cannot resolve constructor 'Intent(anonymus android.view.View.OnClickListener, java.lang.Class minhapackage.Menu)'
```

Comment: Apenas um ponto aqui. Quando você insere um `setLayoutParams` para seu componente, voce passa dois paramestros `FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT` sendo eles `width` e `height` respectivamente. No seu caso, não precisa atribuir a altura e largura, apenas:  `btnJogarNovamente.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(200, 40));`

Comment: Android Studio é uma IDE, editei o titulo pois você quer adicionar o botão é no aplicativo que está a desenvolver

Comment: Bem observado. Obrigado

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O contexto quando se implementa uma classe muda:

```
btnJogarNovamente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Intent it;
        it = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(it);
    }
});
```

Ao executar `new Intent(this, Menu.class);`, o **this** esta referenciando ao seu `OnClickListener` e não a `Activity`.

Neste caso voce deverá referenciar a sua classe:

```
new Intent(NomeDaClasse.this, Menu.class);
```

Comment: Obrigado. Funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: @VitorHerrmann se funcionou marque a resposta como correta